# Join query for these issue

Tags: mysql

```
I have the following two MySQL tables which I need to join:

 A (donor)       B (documents)    
============    =============================
 id | name        id  | profile_img   | ref_id
------------    -----------------------------
  1 | Alex         1  | a.png         | 1
  2 | Bill         2  | b.jpg         | 2
  3 | Cath         3  | c.jpg         | 3
  4 | Dale         4  | d.jpg         | 4
  5 | Evan
  6 | Test
  7 | Test2



SELECT d.name, d.id, c.name, c.ref_id FROM donor d, documents c WHERE 
ref_id = d.id
```

problem is that only those records are fetch which is in donor table rest are not show. i want to show data always when right side match not found

Comment: First, read about JOINs. Then, if you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` for that. It can by done with your syntax(which should not be used!) by a plus sign `+` . I advise you to use only explicit type of joins:

```
SELECT d.name, d.id, COALESCE(c.name,'DefaultVal') , COALESCE(c.ref_id,'DefaultVal')
FROM donor d
LEFT JOIN documents c 
 ON(ref_id = d.id)
```

Comment: Really depends on the day, and how bored I am. Normally I write a comment :) @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT d.name, d.id, c.name, c.ref_id FROM donor d LEFT JOIN documents c ON 
d.id = c.id WHERE c.ref_id=d.id
```